# Solving single non-linear equation involving sum of numpy array with fsolve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

[image]

This non-linear equation comes from summing "k" other equations. Every variable is known here, except m_dot_ev^(T), so this is what I'm trying to find. I sent every term to the LHS in order to have "0" in the RHS and am currently solving via:

```
def non_linear_function(y):
   return sum(X_k_infty_array + (X_k_infty_array - X_k_s_array)/(np.exp(-y/(4*np.pi*rho*R_0*D_k_array))-1)) - 1

m_dot = fsolve(non_linear_function,suitable_RHS_guess)
```

Notice that the variable that we want has become "y" inside the function. I already have a suitable RHS_guess (essentially, the paper which published this equation proposed a more simplified version and showed that the simplified version yields results similar to this complex version. Alternatively, since I compute this result on an iterative manner, I can always use as a guess the converged m_dot obtained from fsolve for the previous iteration in time).

My questions here are: Is there a better way to feed this equation into fsolve? Is fsolve the best tool at all to solve this problem? The method I described above works for a great part of my simulation, but I currently am facing a RuntimeWarning saying no progress is being made on the iterations of fsolve at a time where nothing critical is happening , so I'm wondering if there's a better way to go about doing this. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is good for using fsolve. But fsolve is more sophisticated, meant to be used for multivariable functions.

You could try it with [root_scalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.root_scalar), it let's you to choose the solution method.

If you some information e.g. if `Xoo >  Xs` for all `k` then the is split in two for `y < 0` and for `y > 0`, and it has at most one root. In this case you could use a more predictable method as the [bisection method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html#scipy.optimize.bisect), or some of its improved versions [Brent's method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq) or [Ridder's method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.ridder.html#scipy.optimize.ridder)